# How can I apply a function to a set of .csv files in a particular directory?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

Despite lots of research and several efforts using `lapply` (I think/hope that's the correct `apply` function), I have been unable to achieve the following and would like some guidance.  What I want to do is read in all files in a single directory, merge them all into a single dataframe, making sure that each file has the first seven rows deleted before the merge.

(Note that all files contain the same column headings and contain the same datatypes.)

I have tried this, but it clearly falls short of everything I want to achieve:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv") # Gather a list of everything in the directory that is a .csv file.
aconex <- lapply(files, fread) # Use lapply (I think this is correct) to apply the fread() function (from the data.table package) to each .csv file
```

This results in everything being stored in a vector, whereas I want the output to be a data frame.

There has to be a better approach - I just can't seem to figure it out.

Can anybody suggest a better solution?

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, I have written a `for` loop which partially achieves what I want; the problem is that it only saves a single file's worth of data to the data frame (there are 15 files in total):

```
for(x in list.files(pattern = "*.csv")){
  df <- data.table::fread(x)
  df <- df[-(1:7), ]
  colnames(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))
  df <- df[-(1), ]
}
```

Once the first seven rows have been removed, I then apply the first row as column names and then remove the first row.  Again, what is a better way to achieve this?

Ideally, I want the resulting output to either be x-number of data frames (`df1`, `df2`, .., `dfX`) and I can then merge those, but, again, there has to be a better way - what is it?

Put simply, I want each file to be read into its own data frame, then for the value of `row 8` to be used as the column headings, then the first eight rows removed (I only kept the eighth row in order to use it for the column headings before removing it).

Comment: depending on what you want to do... `list_files<-list.files(pattern = "*.csv") list_result<-lapply(list_files,fread, skip=7, header=T)
result_dataframe<-do.call(list_result, "cbind")` or `list_files<-list.files(pattern = "*.csv") list_result<-lapply(list_files,fread, skip=7, header=T)
result_dataframe<-rbindlist(list_results)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating an [anonymous function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions) that does the reading with `read.csv` and then removes the first seven rows with the `skip` argument. Then you can stick all the `data.frame`s together with `do.call`.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")

#create f, which is a list of data frames
f <- lapply(files, function(m) df <- read.csv(m, skip = 7, header = TRUE))

#stick them all together with do.call-rbind
f_combine <- do.call("rbind", f)
```

If you do need the speed provided by `data.table::fread`, you could modify the code as follows:

```
#create f, which is a list of data frames; modified with fread from data.table
f <- lapply(files, function(m) df <- fread(m, skip = 7))

#use rbindlist this time
f_combine <- rbindlist(f )
```